# Emacs: key bindings with sequences of normal keys

Tags: vim, emacs, key-bindings

What's the Emacs's equivalent of Vim's `imap ab c`? (input-`a`, then input-`b` results in output-`c`)

Comment: By not explaining what that command does, you are limiting your audience to people who know *both* editors.

Comment: @phils edited (cos you got 3 ups;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to set keys in Emacs is with [`global-set-key`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Commands.html), but that's glossing over some of the details; see [Xah Lee's tutorial on defining keys](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/keyboard_shortcuts.html) for more.

Since you're coming from Vim, however, take a look at [`evil-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil), which is a really nice Vim emulation layer for Emacs.

Using `evil`, you could bind a key (or series of them) in, say, insert or normal state with:

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map "a"  'some-command)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "bc" 'some-other-command)
```

You can also do mode-specific keybindings pretty easily.  So, for example, to have a binding affect insert or normal state only in LaTeX mode, you can say:

```
(evil-define-key 'insert LaTeX-mode-map "d"   'another-command)
(evil-define-key 'normal LaTeX-mode-map "efg" 'yet-another-command)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [key-chord.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/key-chord.el) using it you can do:

```
 (key-chord-define-global "hj"     'undo)
```

Comment: Looks like these are chords, not sequences.

Answer (score 1):

`abbrev-mode` *might* be what you're looking for; but you only get the expansion if you type a non-word character after it.

See the manual for details:
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Abbrev` <kbd>RET</kbd>

> an abbrev expands whenever it is present
>   in the buffer just before point and you type a self-inserting
>   whitespace or punctuation character (<SPC>, comma, etc.).  More
>   precisely, any character that is not a word constituent expands an
>   abbrev, and any word-constituent character can be part of an abbrev.
>   The most common way to use an abbrev is to insert it and then insert a
>   punctuation or whitespace character to expand it.

For related built-in functionality, see:
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(autotype) Top` <kbd>RET</kbd>

[CategoryTemplates](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryTemplates) at the Emacs Wiki is likely to be of interest as well.

Comment: And if you're looking for Textmate style snippets, you can check out [`yasnippet`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet).